# not able to use setobject for custom binding in jooq

Tags: java, sql, jooq

```
public class DestinationCustomBinding implements Binding<Object, Destination>{


    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private final Converter<Object, Destination> converter = new DestinationConverter();

    public Converter<Object, Destination> converter() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return converter;
    }

    public void sql(BindingSQLContext<Destination> ctx) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Param<Integer> param = DSL.val(ctx.convert(converter).value(),Integer.class );

        ctx.render().visit(DSL.val(ctx.convert(converter).value(),Integer.class ));
    }

    public void register(BindingRegisterContext<Destination> ctx) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ctx.statement().registerOutParameter(ctx.index(), Types.JAVA_OBJECT);
    }

    public void set(BindingSetStatementContext<Destination> ctx) throws SQLException {


        ctx.statement().setObject(ctx.index(), ctx.convert(converter).value(), null);
     //      ctx.statement().setString(ctx.index(), Objects.toString(ctx.convert(converter).value(), null));
    }

    public void set(BindingSetSQLOutputContext<Destination> ctx) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }

    public void get(BindingGetResultSetContext<Destination> ctx) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ctx.convert(converter).value(ctx.resultSet().getObject(ctx.index()));
    }

    public void get(BindingGetStatementContext<Destination> ctx) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ctx.convert(converter).value(ctx.statement().getObject(ctx.index()));
    }

    public void get(BindingGetSQLInputContext<Destination> ctx) throws SQLException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        throw new SQLFeatureNotSupportedException();
    }

}
```

i want to use setObject instead of setString in public void set(BindingSetStatementContext ctx) , But I am getting the following error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: setObject not implemented
    at java.sql.PreparedStatement.setObject(PreparedStatement.java:1291)
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.setObject(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:371)
    at com.shn.analytics.db.connection.utils.DestinationCustomBinding.set(DestinationCustomBinding.java:53)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultBindContext.bindValue0(DefaultBindContext.java:62)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractBindContext.bindValue(AbstractBindContext.java:127)
    ... 11 more
```

Use case: I am using crate db which accepts a Json like (not Json) objects without quotes
Ex:

```sql
create table test_table ( 
  Id Integer, 
  name STRING, 
  test_Object OBJECT
);

insert into test_table(Id, test_Object) 
values (10, 'test_Name', {city = 'random_city'});
```

How can implement this use case in jooq

Comment: What database / JDBC driver are you using?

Comment: i am using crate db (https://crate.io/) . jdbc driver is (https://crate.io/docs/clients/jdbc/)  postgres and i am using HikariCP datasource to get the connections

Comment: What is the definition of ` DestinationConverter`?

Answer (score 4):

In many JDBC drivers, you cannot use `PreparedStatement.setObject(index, null)` because the JDBC driver needs to know what *type* of `NULL` it should serialise over the wire to the server. I don't know what crate.io expects here (it's not an officially supported database in jOOQ), but the usual options are:

```java
// Using String
stmt.setString(index, null);

// Use setNull()
stmt.setNull(index, Types.OTHER);
```

In the case of the `setNull()` method, it may well be that there's a vendor-specific `Types` value, more specific than `Types.OTHER`.